# RealVNC: Connection only works if I sign in with my home account

Tags: connection, realvnc

I want to make all computers in my network accessable through the RealVNC server - for devices in the network. Unfortunately the connection only works if I'm signed in to my RealVNC Home account at the device I want to connect from. Otherwise I can't connect - regarldess if from smartphone or PC. At the Server I'm signed in, too.
So the IP I'm typing in is probably right as I get it from ipconfig. From within the network I shouldn't need to specify a port. So what is it then?
Maybe a problem regarding RealVNC itself? What is this licensing stuff?

I hope someone can help, as I don't get behind the idea, what the RealVNC account is meant for. I wanna enable my family to access the computer from all their smartphones and I'm unsure if we should all create own accounts, use just one or none.

Have a great day!

Nicolas

Answer (score 0):

With VNC Connect Home subscriptions, direct connections aren't supported so you cannot connect using IP address or hostname. You can only connect using the computer under your team and you can only do that when signed into VNC Viewer.
You can invite 2 other people into your team from manage.realvnc.com to give them remote access.
Hope that helps!